# Error on Contact update in Sandbox when workflow triggers update of picklist field using a Global Picklist (Beta as of Summer '16)

Tags: workflow, sandbox, contact

I received the following error upon trying to save a contact:

> An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!
> Error ID: 864486382-11949 (1204153959)

Here are the details:

Custom field "Chats" (`Chats__c`) is a number, defaulted to 0.

Workflow with formula:

```
AND (
    PRIORVALUE(Chats__c)=0,
    Chats__c > 0,
    Chats__c < 10
)
```

Three things happen upon formula evaluating to `True`:

- Email alert is created with `Email field: Email` and a template.
- Task is created with due date of today, marked closed
- A picklist field is updated to an existing value in the list.

This workflow is successful for one contact but not for another. The only difference is the name and email of the contact. They belong to the same account, and every other detail is the same.

Can someone please help me understand what I might be doing wrong? I did a search for the error code but found no results.

Comment: These are called [gacks](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html). Inevitably, the solution is one of these three: (1) call support (2) selectively reduce the scope of the problem until you find the cause and then workaround (self-cure) (3) SFDC hotfixes Summer 16 and problem goes away

Comment: Thank you. I've isolated the issue to the Field update workflow task. It seems that it's a result of the Global Picklist being used with the field, as I cloned the field and changed the picklist to manual values and the workflow worked as intended.

Comment: that's great. if you would be so kind, please reword your question title and post an answer as to the workaround so others who get similar error can benefit from your analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the picklist field and recreated it using manual picklist values. The workflow fires as intended.